# Kotlin java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6

So, when I try to autowire custom filter (which is written in Java) inside my `SecurityConfig.kt` class, it throws an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

here is my `SecurityConfig.kt`:

```
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsServiceImpl? = null

    @Autowired
    private val unauthorizedHandler: AuthEntryPointJwt? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.userDetailsService<UserDetailsService?>(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationJwtTokenFilter(): AuthTokenFilter? {
        return AuthTokenFilter()
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager? {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder? {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(httpServletRequest);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String email = jwtUtils.getEmailFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the full exception message (which should contain the name of the class which is not defined.

Comment: NoClassDefs are always because of bad dependencies, also post your pom.xml